# Demonstrating convergence of a sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis

I want to demonstrate that the following sequence of functions:

$g_n(x)=\begin{cases}
     nx & \quad  x\in \left[0,  \frac{1}{n}\right] \\
      1& \quad x\in \left[ \frac{1}{n},1\right]\\
   \end{cases}$

converges to $g(x)=1$.

I know intuitively that this is true because as n goes to infinity $g_n(x)$ converges to 1. However, I am not sure how to rigorously demonstrate that g(x) converges to 1 on [0,1].

Comment: Converges to 1 _how_? Pointwise, almost everywhere, etc.

Answer (score 1):

$g_n$ converges pointwise to 1 only on $]0,1]$. In this example you have $g(0)=0$ because $g_n(0)=0~ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

To prove your assumption (on $]0,1]$ and for pointwise convergence), take any number $x_0 \in ]0,1]$ and prove that there is an $N$ such as for any $n \geq N$, $g_n(x_0)=1$.